# Allowing navigation on more than 2 views

Tags: ios, iphone

So I am trying to create an iphone app and I am trying to set up the navigation controller. I got it to work from one view to another and then back.(code below) Is there a way to do it for multiple views? For instance, starting from the beginning pressing one button that changes to another view then pressing another button that goes to another different view. How would I implement the navigation controller to work without using storyboard and actually programming it? Any tips would be appreciated thanks.

This is in AppDelegate:

```
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    LoginViewController *loginController = [[LoginViewController alloc] init];
    UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc]     initWithRootViewController:loginController];
    self.window.rootViewController = navController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
```

This is in one of the button methods in one of the views:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:mainViewController animated:YES];
```

Comment: [mainViewController.navigationController pushViewController:anotherViewController animated:YES] ?

Comment: push the necessary views into the stack as you have pushed one already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is what the navigation controller do.

You can navigate to multiple views like this;

> To navigate from main view to secondViewController

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:secondViewController animated:YES];
```

The current navigation stack is mainViewcontroller -> secondViewController

> From second View to third View

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:thirdViewController animated:YES];
```

The current navigation stack is mainViewcontroller -> secondViewController - >thirdViewController

> To go back to previous view you can call

```
 [self popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Comment: Sorry I meant have explained this incorrectly. So I have the first view which has a navigation bar, then I click a button and that goes to another view (view 2) and that has a navigation bar that has the back button, but now if I click another button in view 2 that goes to a 3rd view the navigation bar doesn't show up. Any tips? Your suggestion doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Nvm it works haha it was just being weird when I tried it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

for 1 to 2 view

[self.navigationController pushViewController:secondViewController animated:YES];

from 2 to 3 view

[self.navigationController pushViewController:thirdViewController animated:YES];

back from 3 to 2 view

[self popViewControllerAnimated:YES];

Comment: Sorry I meant have explained this incorrectly. So I have the first view which has a navigation bar, then I click a button and that goes to another view (view 2) and that has a navigation bar that has the back button, but now if I click another button in view 2 that goes to a 3rd view the navigation bar doesn't show up. Any tips? Your suggestion doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Nvm it works haha it was just being weird when I tried it. Thanks!